# Handling html radio buttons with php

Tags: php, html, radio-button

So i have been trying for awhile here to handle radio buttons with php and cant seem to get it to work right. Im sure its just an error on my code that im not seeing maybe you guys can give me a hand. Im not going to post all of my code because some has information that i dont want to give out so i will post enough so that the problem can get solved. Thanks!

the code should send an email formatted as so

```
$m->Subject = 'Docket-Solutions Order Form';
$m->Body = 'From: ' . $fields['name'] . ' (' . $fields['email'] . ') ' .     $fields['category'] . ' ' . $fields['priority'] . '<p>' . $fields['message'] .     '</p>';
```

with that said i have it set up to email me and it emails me everything except the priority box that is checked. for example if low-priority is check then in the email i want it to tell me so and so on. in the email it should say "low-priority"

html code

```
<div class="4u 12u(narrower)">

<input type="radio" id="priority-low" name="priority" <?php if (isset($_POST['priority']) && $_POST['priority']=="Low Priority") echo "checked";?> checked>

<label for="priority-low">Low Priority</label>
</div>
```

Php code

```
if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message'])) {
$fields = [
'name' => $_POST['name'],
'email' => $_POST['email'],
'subject' => $_POST['subject'],
'message' => $_POST['message']
];

foreach($fields as $field => $data) {
    if(empty($data)) {
        $errors[] = 'The ' . $field . ' field is required.';
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: So, you want us to find the problem and give you the solution? Oh boy.

Comment: Also the PHP part has nothing to do with radio.

Comment: The question is why doesn't the code that i have for the radio buttons work i dont want you to to give me a solution. i already wrote all this code by myself just here trying to figure out why it wont work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just remove the last "checked" in your HTML code to change the state of your radio button via PHP.
Furthermore you should give the radio button a value to print it in the mail.

```
<input type="radio" id="priority-low" name="priority" value="Low Priority" <?php if (isset($_POST['priority']) && $_POST['priority']=="Low Priority") echo "checked";?>>
```

Comment: What would that do i dont understand

Comment: Currently, your radio button is checked every time, because you use the html attribute "checked" even if your POST value is not set.

Comment: Ok i understand that but that has yet to fix my problem, when the email is sent where it is suppose to say "low-priority" it says "on" for some reason.

Comment: When you use `<input ... <?php if (/*your condition*/) echo "checked";?> checked>`, the word  *checked* will be there once if the condition is not fulfilled. Otherwise, *checked* will be there **twice**

Comment: @BestThereEverWas could you elaborate *what* the code should achieve? I can't see that any mail is sent in your example code

Comment: Yeah, the email should be sent and formatted as so ill redo the upper post

Comment: @BestThereEverWas check out the answer again